# Android Studio Complaining of Unsupported Type "RelativeLayout"

Tags: java, android

I'm attempting to compile my project but Android Studio is giving the following error:

> Error:Error: Unsupported type 'RelativeLayout'

Anyone have an idea why?

Cheers

Comment: please add where is this error coming i.e. your logcat and your code

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_main">

<Relative Layout>
```

Make sure of adding atleast these lines , if possible then paste xml code then you can get better help